# Get height of screen without title bar/navigation bar and status bar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

i'm currently trying to get the height of the usable screen (excluding anything like navigation bar, title bar, or status bar. I tries using the code:

```
var height = Application.Current.MainPage.Height
```

However this code gets the height including everything. So how do I get the height of just the usable screen?

Comment: This depends on where you need this information. Could you edit the question to give some more context. This also seems a bit like an [X/Y-Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: @PaulKertscher yeah im working on making a UI with 4 rectangular buttons to fill the screen so im making it so that the buttons are half the with and height of the screen, however it isnt working right because it taking the height of the whole screen including the title bar at the top.